# Docker Swarm - API method to stop a container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

It there any http command to tell the docker swarm to stop a container?

Answer (score 0):

[`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) is enough to stop a container, swarm or not.

In [swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/), you have the notion of *service*, with [`service create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/), but that doesn't change the way you stop one container.

You can use the [remote API for an http call stopping a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/stop-a-container):

```
 POST /containers/(id or name)/stop
```

> Stop the container id
>
> Example request:

```
 POST /containers/e90e34656806/stop?t=5 HTTP/1.1
```